# Is there a way to include an array in a where: $or clause with sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a array of Ids `teamsIdsSelected = ['1', '5', .., 'X']`

Then, from my table named 'Challenge' I want to get all the the challenges that are linked to each teamId from the array teamsIdsSelected. So far, this is what I tried:

1. Using this function:

```js
    createWhereClause(column, field) {
        return models.sequelize.where(
            models.sequelize.literal(`${column} in (`),
            `'${field}'`,
            models.sequelize.literal(')'))
    },
```

2. Getting the challenges this way:

```js
    const challenges = await Challenge.findAndCountAll({
        where: {
            team_id: createWhereClause(team_id, teamsIdsSelected)
        }
    })
```

But it doesn't work, I only obtain the challenge with team_id equal to the last item of `teamsIdsSelected = teamsIdsSelected.slice(-1)[0]`
For instance if `teamsIdsSelected = ['1', '4', '7']`, the where clause at the end (when I look at the log) is only `"where challenge.team_id = 7"`.

What I would actually like is an OR condition that would take all challenges that match either 1, 4, or 7 as a team_id. Is there a fast way to do it without creating a for loop ?

Let me know if you need more precision about my issue. Thanks.

Comment: `Op.or` or `Op.in` http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html#operators

Comment: @bato3 thanks so much, i didn't know about the op.in ! how do i signal your comment as the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
const challenges = await Challenge.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
        team_id: { [Op.in]: teamsIdsSelected }
    }
})
```